# How to find 'proguard.cfg' file

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, proguard

i'm trying to modify my **proguard.cfg** and add some lines to keep library classes.

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepclassmembers class ** {
    @com.squareup.otto.Subscribe public *;
    @com.squareup.otto.Produce public *;
}
```

but i can't find the **proguard.cfg** file as you see in picture below : 
[image]

**Build.Gradle :**

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Comment: its same 'proguard-rules.pro', you can add project specific ProGuard rules there

Comment: @darwin should i add  `-keep class ...`  in `proguard-rules.pro`  file ??

Comment: yes, also if you want to enable proguard in debug build as well then add those configuration in your app build gradle file

Comment: @darwin thanks so much